WeKan instance hosted at 8080 despite never setting it up
I accidentally went to my ubuntu server 8080 port and was greeted with this:
WeKan login screen
This was not me. All I did on this machine was run a Minecraft server and OwnCloud server with Docker. Did I get hacked?
